# Why can I not close a form in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I cannot close one of my forms programmatically. Can someone help me?

Here's the code:

```
    private void WriteCheck_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SelectBankAccountDialog sbad = new SelectBankAccountDialog();
        DialogResult result = sbad.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) {
            this.Close();
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sbad.bankaccountID.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As configurator mentioned (in comments), the form must be shown before it can be closed, so, instead of the *Load* event, you should be doing this in the *Shown* event instead.

If you don't want the form visible for the Dialog box, I guess you can wrap the event code in a Visible = false;

In summary, the basic code would be

```
    private void WriteCheck_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Visible = false;
        SelectBankAccountDialog sbad = new SelectBankAccountDialog();
        DialogResult result = sbad.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) {
            this.Close();
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sbad.bankaccountID.ToString());
        Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: it can be visible, it just didn't have it as such.

Comment: That's cool. It's a gotcha that caught be a year back, so happy to pass it on.

Answer (score 3):

By calling `Form.Close()`, the form should close, but not until all waiting events have been processed. You also still have a chance to cancel the form closing in the `FormClosing` event.

First, you'll probably want to `return` after your call to `this.Close()`. If it still doesn't close, step through your code and see what is happening. You may have to set and check a "forciblyClose" flag and return from any other processing methods before it'll actually close.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that windows won't let a form close on it's load method. I have to show the dialog on construction, and then if the dialog result is cancel I have to throw an exception and catch the exception on form creation.

[This place](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/topic18413.aspx) talks more about it

Comment: It's a little more subtle than that; the Close() call does close the form, but that is before the Show() or ShowDialog() has had the chance to show the form - so what happens is the form is first hidden, then shown (outside the Load event).